# Why were there so many known (and caught) stage coach robbers?

Tags: old-west

I mean, the most simplest way to prevent getting caught is leaving no tracks behind. E.g. you should have three men (should be enough, in my opinion), and then set a trap for the stage coach. As soon as the coach triggers the trap, kill everyone -> no witnesses, no penalty, nobody knows you (and you get extremely fast rich...).

Comment: Isn't this quite conjectural?

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: I believe the answer to your question lies in psychology, not in history.  I believe there are many people who would be willing to rob for a living, but would draw the line at murder.  I also doubt your conclusion that murderers who are thorough are less likely to be caught; law enforcement is highly motivated to catch cold blooded murderers.

Comment: This question includes no research.   How many stage coach robberies occurred? How many robbers were there? how many were caught?  How many were known but not caught?  How much money could be made from the average stage coach robbery?

Comment: LOL. What's next? Your plan for robbing a supermarket loaded with cash after Thanksgiving weekend?

Comment: To paraphrase a robber when asked why he robbed banks "Because that's where the money is".  Stagecoaches were used to transfer valuable things, like money between banks.

Comment: The surest way to get caught at anything is to blab about it afterwards. "three men"? And you think they could all keep quite indefinitely? This has not changed since the stagecoach days, and is still how many criminals are finally caught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Most stage coach robberies were never solved](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0762741279). The Wild West was - to be redundant - a wild, lawless place, so this is no surprise. Many robberies were simply not pursued because lawmen weren't sufficiently funded, many had to use their own funds to round up a limited posse, or more often, simply posted a reward which is usually funded from a portion of the recovered treasure.

Since it was very likely that you could get away with stage coach robbery, why up the ante by committing murder, when it doesn't increase your payday? [Robbers were typically sentenced 5-15 years, whereas first-degree murder was a capital offense](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=oTY--EXdfGcC&lpg=PA9&ots=I00Jv07ijO&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false). Committing more serious crimes will simply attract more attention from the law and bounty hunters.

Comment: the idea that the "wild west" was lawless is a myth created by Hollywood. It wasn't, but trained law enforcement people were few and far between. That left a lot of law enforcement on the hands of vigilantes, bounty hunters, and posses. But there definitely were laws and efforts to enforce them.

Comment: @jwenting isn't that what Hollywood depicts anyway? The lack of law enforcement? I'm not aware of any Hollywood works that depict a lack of law in this era, certainly not against robberies or murders.

Comment: I don't think that you can tell that someone murder the stagecoach guys, if they are gone (no corpse -> no murder?). Furthermore, I don't think that you can find out who did the robbery (because of no witnesses again). So, my payday is extremely decreased, because no one is thinking of me as the guilty one...

Comment: Murder attracts more law enforcement interest than robbery by far.  And there are always witnesses to a murder, the ones that did it.  You have to shut them up as well.

Comment: @congusbongus Hollywood depicts mostly corrupt sheriffs and Robin Hood style good guy criminals. IOW "the Law" being bad. There might be laws, but they're either not enforced by the designated men or they're bad laws and it's "the good fight" to break them and get away with it.

Comment: @jwenting True Grit is not how you describe, nor is Shane, Wild Wild West, The Man who shot Liberty Valance, or dozens of other movies.  Even movies like Little Big Man, Dances with Wolves or Blazing Saddles(the main bad guy was from the East) do not convey this sense of lawlessness you're blaming Hollywood for.

Also, Robin-Hood-style criminals do not exist in *most* mythos about the Old West because the affluent, rich, and poorly defended aristocracy do not really exist in the mtyhos either.  The closest I can reference is Zoro, who is from that time period, but based in LA.

Answer (score 1):

For one, killing people goes against people's conscience; people don't typically kill just for the sake of it. The witness is stranded on the road side and all he can say is he saw someone in a mask.

Two, you don't bite the hand that feeds you; if you kill the rich, you will deter the rich from travelling in the future. If they are a little out of pocket they may see it more as an inconvenience than a threat.